# How to describe square brackets in regular expression in XSD

Tags: regex, xml, xsd

I have a element(type string) with a pattern like this `[^<>/]+` when I write it as a regular expression.0

But when I put this in my XSD file, there is an error message. It seems that the square brackets cause this error.

How can I make it right?

I want to have a pattern which describes that no square brackets or slash should appear.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Terminology note:** `<` and `>` are ***angle*** or ***pointy*** brackets; `[` and `]` are ***square*** brackets.

It's *one* of the angle (`<` and `>`), not the *square*, brackets that is the problem.  In XML, which is what XSDs are written in, the less than character (`<`) in particular must be escaped as `&lt;` when used other than as the start of a tag.

```
<xs:pattern value="[^&lt;>/]+"/>
```

The greater than symbol (`>`) is ok in this context.

Answer (score 2):

Use `&lt;` instead of `<` and `&gt;` instead of `>`:

```
<xs:pattern value="[^&lt;&gt;/]+"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @CoronaS.: Actually, my answer was the first, and it is common practice to accept these answers first. Besides, it is a bad idea to keep `>` unserialized. I have lots of trouble at work with such XML files.

Comment: @CoronaS., Wiktor has amazing regex skills and helps a ton of people here.  Feel free to switch the accept to him if you'd like.   I'll give him an upvote even, regardless.  I just wanted to explain a bit more than he had in his answer -- that's all.  Cheers.

Comment: @kjhughes,I know that it is common practice to accept the first answer. I've accepted your answer because you've more than Wiktor explained. It's hard to choice. But I've made my choice. I'll not change it. I really appreciate both of your answers. I hope that he can understand. Have a nice day both of you!

Comment: Yes, it is fine, I do not like to change accepted answers either.